# Update query in pre sql of source qualifier is running but not commiting the table?

Tags: oracle, informatica, informatica-powercenter

[image]Below given query is executed using Source qualifier in Informatica.

Pre SQL has the below query.

```
Update CTLSTAGE.VMR226DEV_HSD_SUB A
  set A.ATM_IP_IND = 'ATM'
where (A.SW_SITE_CD,A.DEV_NM) = (
                                 select SW_SITE_CD,DEV_NM
                                 from CTLSTAGE.ATM_IP_REF
                                 where FTTC_E_IND = 'Y'
                                ) ;
COMMIT ;
```

Which is running but not committing in database.

[image]

Comment: Pre-SQL and Post-SQL always have an implicit "commit" at the end, so you can remove the "COMMIT;" part from your query. Since your logfile says "Completed Pre SQL ... successfully", I would say that worked correctly. Are you sure the query is correct, you're using the correct connection + user and the update is actually doing something?

Comment: Thanks socken23, I have checked the query , its working fine in oracle , however not working in informatica. Rows are not updated by the query. I have checked the connection , there is nothing wrong with connection setting is there any way to test the result of update query in informatica, i tried with verbose but couldn't help it.

Comment: If the query is running fine in `Oracle` and when you have `validated` it did not throw error it means the query is fine. I can only suggest you to check the correct `Schema` if this `CTLSTAGE` is the correct one you are referring to. Additionally check the DB connections in `Work flow`manager

Comment: I checked the schema, even its showing query executed successfully in session log. Check the DB connection. Attaching the DB connection screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I presume it's running fine. Add additional statements to diagnose, like:

```
insert into someAuditTable 
select SW_SITE_CD,DEV_NM from CTLSTAGE.ATM_IP_REF where FTTC_E_IND = 'Y'
```

and

```
insert into someAuditTable2 
select * from CTLSTAGE.VMR226DEV_HSD_SUB A where (A.SW_SITE_CD,A.DEV_NM) = (
                             select SW_SITE_CD,DEV_NM
                             from CTLSTAGE.ATM_IP_REF
                             where FTTC_E_IND = 'Y'
                            ) ;
```

BTW:
Does this kind of tuple comparison work fine? Looks odd to me:

```
(A.SW_SITE_CD,A.DEV_NM) = (select SW_SITE_CD,DEV_NM ...)
```